# Signals: Kernel-generated only?

Tags: linux, kernel, signal

Can processes really "generate" signals or they just request the kernel to send the signal on their behalf?

And what about hardware interrupts? Do they get translated to software interrupts? Like, can the CPU interrupt a process directly? or through the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals get delivered by the kernel.

Any interrupt generated by the CPU will get intercepted by the kernel (this is a cornerstone of the whole "kernel keeps control always" idea).

What are you trying to do? It is better to state the whole problem, you might get stuck in your approach when there are much better ones available.

Comment: No need for that, I just wanted to have a clear picture in my head of how signals get delivered before I "listen" to any abstractions by other textbooks/materials. Thanks!